# enum declaration in header file

Tags: c, enums, header-files

I have files A.c , B.c and B.h .
In A.c there is an

```
enum CMD{
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
};
```

and later in that file there is

```
bool function(...){
//...
enum CMD data_type = FIRST;
//...
}
```

In file B.c I need to use

```
if (data_type == FIRST){...}
```

I tried to include in B.h this:

```
extern enum CMD data_type;
```

And included #include "B.h" in A.c and B.c .
All files are in the propper folders of the project.
But no cigar :(
The line in B.c gives this:

```
20: identifier "FROM_SMS" is undefined
70: incomplete type is not allowed
```

How do I make this work. The A.c file is writen by someone else and I'm modifiing the code with B.c . The original code is  a mess and I wan to fidlle with it as less as possible :)
Architecture ie STM32 and I'm using uVision 3 IDE.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to show some of your *actual* code, not this `FIRST`...

Comment: Sorry, there's strict company policies about this kind of things :(

Comment: About what kind of things?  You don't have to show the actual code; you just have to produce an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) that is *not* the company code but produces the equivalent error messages from the compiler.

Comment: ~20K views, zero edits, 1 upvote. jeez

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An enum is a type, you should put in in the .h.

`extern` keyword is for variables.

Edit: Sorry, I had badly read your code.

Here the problem is that you will try to use the enum without having it defined.
Think that when a compiler compiles something, it takes every .c file separately, and then "copies" the content of the include into the c file.

So here you will have b.c which includes b.h but since the declaration of your type is in a.c, the compiler has no way of knowing it, hence throwing an error when trying to compile b.c.

To solve it, just declare your type at the top of b.h and include it in both files, or create a "myenum.h" file which you include in the .h / .c files that require it.

Comment: I commented out the enum CMD{...}; definition (declaration?) in A.c and included it in B.h . But now it gives me 'Undefined data_type symbol in B.o file'

Comment: It is because data_type is local to your function `bool function(...)`.

You need to declare it in a.c outside of a function, then hope `bool function(...)` is called before you need it in b.c and write : 

`extern enum CMD data_type;` on your b.c, outside of any other function definition too.

Comment: It compiled. I won't be using the 'bool function()' in the end of my given task so I guess it's ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is just an other type of `define`. It only works in current translation unit.